# Prevent insert mode in vim

Tags: vim

I often like to have a copy of the file that I am working on open on a second monitor, usually to assist with writing tests. I sometimes mindlessly attempt to edit it on this monitor, rather than the most up to date one. To prevent this, I have been setting read only mode with `:set ro` but that doesn't prevent me from making changes, it only prevents me from saving.

I would like a lock that turns off the ability to go into insert mode. I could create a toggle that remaps all the insert mode keys, but I was wondering if there is a better solution?

Comment: Could always open it up in a different program, `less` for example, that doesn't allow editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. `:set nomodifiable` in the buffer you want to mark read-only. This is used by plugins like taglist to create non-modifiable buffers.

Answer (score 4):

You can open with the argument -M.  This prevents edits to the buffer.

Comment: This also works, the answer I selected fits better with my workflow.